# Ayuda con una consulta en Postgres que deseo pasar a SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Buenos días amigos tengo la siguiente consulta en postgres.

`select 
distinct on (c.cod_socio) tbl.*, h.cod_oficina, h.cod_transaccion, h.num_transaccion, h.num_sec, h.fec_movimiento
from sgf_det_mov_his h 
inner join sgf_cuenta c on c.cod_producto = h.cod_producto and c.cod_cuenta = h.cod_cuenta
inner join sgf_tran t on t.cod_transaccion = h.cod_transaccion and t.cod_oficina = h.cod_oficina and t.cod_tipo_transaccion in ('DA', 'DP','NC') 
inner join 
(
select sgf_cuenta.cod_socio, sum(trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_efectivo,0) + trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_cheques,0)) as total 
from sgf_det_mov_his, sgf_cuenta, sgf_tran
where 
sgf_cuenta.cod_producto = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_producto
and sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_cuenta
and sgf_det_mov_his.sts_mov = 'A'
and sgf_tran.cod_transaccion = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_transaccion
and sgf_tran.cod_oficina = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_oficina
and sgf_cuenta.cod_producto <> 2
and sgf_tran.cod_tipo_transaccion in ('DA', 'DP','NC')
and isnull(sgf_tran.cod_uaf,0) > 0 and isnull(sgf_tran.cod_uaf,0) not in (71)
and sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta not in (select cod_cuenta from sgf_credito 
                where sgf_credito.cod_producto = sgf_cuenta.cod_producto
                and sgf_credito.cod_cuenta = sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta
                and sts_operacion in ('A'))
and date(sgf_det_mov_his.fec_movimiento)  between '2015-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
group by sgf_cuenta.cod_socio
having sum(trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_efectivo,0) + trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_cheques,0))>=5000
) tbl on tbl.cod_socio = c.cod_socio
where 
date(h.fec_movimiento)  between '2015-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
order by c.cod_socio, h.fec_movimiento desc`

Ahora esta consulta necesito ejecutar en SQL-SERVER. Tengo hecho solamente los siguientes cambios.

`select 
distinct on (c.cod_socio) tbl.*, h.cod_oficina, h.cod_transaccion, h.num_transaccion, h.num_sec, h.fec_movimiento
from sgf_det_mov_his h 
inner join sgf_cuenta c on c.cod_producto = h.cod_producto and c.cod_cuenta = h.cod_cuenta
inner join sgf_tran t on t.cod_transaccion = h.cod_transaccion and t.cod_oficina = h.cod_oficina and t.cod_tipo_transaccion in ('DA', 'DP','NC') 
inner join 
(
select sgf_cuenta.cod_socio, sum(round(sgf_det_mov_his.val_efectivo,0) + round(sgf_det_mov_his.val_cheques,0)) as total 
from sgf_det_mov_his, sgf_cuenta, sgf_tran
where 
sgf_cuenta.cod_producto = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_producto
and sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_cuenta
and sgf_det_mov_his.sts_mov = 'A'
and sgf_tran.cod_transaccion = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_transaccion
and sgf_tran.cod_oficina = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_oficina
and sgf_cuenta.cod_producto <> 2
and sgf_tran.cod_tipo_transaccion in ('DA', 'DP','NC')
and isnull(sgf_tran.cod_uaf,0) > 0 and isnull(sgf_tran.cod_uaf,0) not in (71)
and sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta not in (select cod_cuenta from sgf_credito 
                where sgf_credito.cod_producto = sgf_cuenta.cod_producto
                and sgf_credito.cod_cuenta = sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta
                and sts_operacion in ('A'))
and convert(date, sgf_det_mov_his.fec_movimiento)  between '2015-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
group by sgf_cuenta.cod_socio
having sum(round(sgf_det_mov_his.val_efectivo,0) + round(sgf_det_mov_his.val_cheques,0))>=5000
) tbl on tbl.cod_socio = c.cod_socio
where 
date(h.fec_movimiento)  between '2015-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
order by c.cod_socio, h.fec_movimiento desc`

Los errores que me presenta son los siguientes.

`Mens. 156, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 2
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'on'.
Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 26
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'tbl'.`

Agradecería de mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no estoy seguro si te vaya a traer datos, pero la sintaxis correcta de SQL Server sería así:

```
select
  distinct(c.cod_socio),
  tbl.*,
  h.cod_oficina,
  h.cod_transaccion,
  h.num_transaccion,
  h.num_sec,
  h.fec_movimiento
from
  sgf_det_mov_his h
  inner join sgf_cuenta c on c.cod_producto = h.cod_producto
  and c.cod_cuenta = h.cod_cuenta
  inner join sgf_tran t on t.cod_transaccion = h.cod_transaccion
  and t.cod_oficina = h.cod_oficina
  and t.cod_tipo_transaccion in ('DA', 'DP', 'NC')
  inner join (
    select
      sgf_cuenta.cod_socio,
      sum(
        round(sgf_det_mov_his.val_efectivo, 0) + round(sgf_det_mov_his.val_cheques, 0)
      ) as total
    from
      sgf_det_mov_his,
      sgf_cuenta,
      sgf_tran
    where
      sgf_cuenta.cod_producto = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_producto
      and sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_cuenta
      and sgf_det_mov_his.sts_mov = 'A'
      and sgf_tran.cod_transaccion = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_transaccion
      and sgf_tran.cod_oficina = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_oficina
      and sgf_cuenta.cod_producto <> 2
      and sgf_tran.cod_tipo_transaccion in ('DA', 'DP', 'NC')
      and isnull(sgf_tran.cod_uaf, 0) > 0
      and isnull(sgf_tran.cod_uaf, 0) not in (71)
      and sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta not in (
        select
          cod_cuenta
        from
          sgf_credito
        where
          sgf_credito.cod_producto = sgf_cuenta.cod_producto
          and sgf_credito.cod_cuenta = sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta
          and sts_operacion in ('A')
      )
      and convert(date, sgf_det_mov_his.fec_movimiento) between '2015-01-01'
      and '2019-01-01'
    group by
      sgf_cuenta.cod_socio
    having
      sum(
        round(sgf_det_mov_his.val_efectivo, 0) + round(sgf_det_mov_his.val_cheques, 0)
      ) >= 5000
  ) tbl on tbl.cod_socio = c.cod_socio
where
  convert(DATE,h.fec_movimiento) between '2015-01-01'
  and '2019-01-01'
order by
  c.cod_socio,
  h.fec_movimiento desc
```

Comment: Exelente muchas gracias por tu ayuda.